# What do the levels stand for in French Air Traffic Service Levels?

Tags: air-traffic-control, notam, france

I am planning a flight to Le Touquet (LFAT) in France next week, I've been told that ATC is not open all days so I've checked the NOTAMS. This seems applicable but I'm not sure I'm interpreting it correctly:

> LFFA-B3753/14  A) LFAT  LE TOUQUET PARIS PLAGE B) 2014 Aug 01  07:00
>   C) 2014 Aug 31  23:59 E) FIRE AND RESCUE HOURS OF SERVICE: 
>   0700-0900 1500-1800    : LEVEL 2 
>   0900-1500              : LEVEL 4 
>   SAUF 15,16,22,23,26-29 : LEVEL 2 ATS HOURS OF SERVICE LEVEL 5 O/R, PPR 24H
>   TO OPR  PHONE: +33(0)3 21 05 03 99  FAX: +33(0)3 21 05 59 34 LEVEL 1
>   OUTSIDE ATS HOURS OF SERVICE.

I think what this is saying is that it is operating at level 2 ATC hours of service except  (Sauf) on the 15,16,22,23,and 26-29th of August, but level 1 all other hours. I think what this means is that next week on weekdays it will be operating at level 2 hours of service. I also think that level 2 means 07-09:00Z and 15-18:00Z, and during this service level 5 will be offered, but all other times level 1 will be offered.

So I think that if I go on those days listed and times listed the tower will be open, otherwise it will be closed (I'm assuming that's what level 1 means), and that I will need to use French non-towered procedures, including French calls.

I'd like to know if I've made the right interpretation, and if there's a source of information about ATC levels in France. I've scoured the web for a couple of hours with no result.

So what are level 2 hours of service, and what service is provided? What is provided with level 1 ATS?

Comment: Would you need to make your non-towered calls in French, or could you do so in English? (Please note, no disrespect of France or it's language intended, I'm curious if pilots there (presumed local on a non-towered day) would be willing/able to use English.)

Comment: @CGCampbell I don't know about France, in Germany it's published in the AD section of the AIP (roughly equivalent to the A/FD) which languages are acceptable.

Comment: @CGCampbell, they have to be in French. I'm not as worried about making calls in French as much as understanding other calls. I've heard recordings and it's unintelligible to non-native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

This NOTAM concerns the fire and rescue level not the ATS operating hours.

You can find the description of the fire and rescue levels [here](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000464146&dateTexte=).

The reference of the ATS hours is to say the level is raised during the opening hours of the ATS.

The ATS opening hours are available on the [Visual Access Chart](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/fr/..%5CPDF_AIPparSSection%5CVAC%5CAD%5C2%5C1410_AD-2.LFAT.pdf) from the SIA. (French service for aeronautical information)

Where you have on last page:

> SUMMER 0700 - 1800

Finally for the language, you have to speak French when the ATS is closed.